# Error when calling global_variables_initializer in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code in `TensorFlow`:

```
def func(a):
    b = tf.Variable(10) * a
    return a
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(func(tf.constant(4))))
```

It works well. But when I substitute `a` with `b` as follows:

```
def func(a):
    b = tf.Variable(10) * a
    return b
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(func(tf.constant(4))))
```

It gets the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call
>    last)
>   c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in _do_call(self, fn, *args)    1138     try:
>   -> 1139       return fn(*args)    1140     except errors.OpError as e:
>
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options,
>   run_metadata)    1120                                  feed_dict,
>   fetch_list, target_list,
>   -> 1121                                  status, run_metadata)    1122
>
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py in **exit**(self, type,
>   value, traceback)
>        88             try:
>   ---> 89                 next(self.gen)
>        90             except StopIteration:
>
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py
>   in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
>       465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
>   --> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
>       467   finally:
>
> FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value
>   Variable_94    [[Node: Variable_94/read = IdentityT=DT_INT32,
>   _class=["loc:@Variable_94"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         4 with tf.Session() as sess:
>         5     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
>   ----> 6     print(sess.run(func(tf.constant(4))))
>
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>       787     try:
>       788       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
>   --> 789                          run_metadata_ptr)
>       790       if run_metadata:
>       791         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
>
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>       995     if final_fetches or final_targets:
>       996       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
>   --> 997                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
>       998     else:
>       999       results = []
>
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options,
>   run_metadata)    1130     if handle is None:    1131       return
>   self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
>   -> 1132                            target_list, options, run_metadata)    1133     else:    1134       return self._do_call(_prun_fn,
>   self._session, handle, feed_dict,
>
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in _do_call(self, fn, *args)    1150         except KeyError:    1151 
>   pass
>   -> 1152       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)    1153     1154   def _extend_graph(self):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first piece of code you don't use the `tf.Variable(10)` so it doesn't matter if it hasn't been initialized, while in your second piece of code you do try to evaluate it, and so TensorFlow complains that it hasn't been initialized.

In your code the `Variable` is defined (when the `func` method is called) after the initialization is done.

```
def func(a):
    b = tf.Variable(10) * a
    return b

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) # At this stage the TensorFlow graph is empty
    print(sess.run(func(tf.constant(4)))) # The func method is called, it defines the `tf.Variable(10)`
                                          # and tries to evaluate `b` which depends on it.
```

In the following piece, the `tf.Variable(10)` is defined before the initializing op is run.

```
b = func(tf.constant(4)) # tf.Variable(10) is defined
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) # tf.Variable(10) is initialized
    print(sess.run(b))
```

Comment: would you explain your code more? the inner b is different from the outer one?

Comment: The variable is only defined when `func` is called. See my updated answer.